# Overwrite CSS of Instaemail plugin popup

Tags: plugins, email, css

I am using instaemail plugin on my wordpress for sending a post by email and I am trying to customize popup window, but seems that I can not overwrite Id or I don't know how to do it. Same popup you can find on link above if you click on email (try it)

I had success with changing wraper color and classes by putting in style.css

```
div#pf-email-wrapper {
    background-color: rgba(09, 85, 3, 0.50);
}
```

but how to change (overwrite URL)

```
.email-sprite{
  background: url('/images/email/email-app-sprite.png') no-repeat;
}
```

or change color of

```
.pf-email label {
  color:#356da9; }
```

So the CSS in style.css would overwrite default CSS of Instamail script
It is not problem in priority  It is in calling the class in style.css probably

> P.S. Is there any plugin which for "send to friend" button and to 
>   customization of popup and customization of email template

Comment: While override of the CSS itself is off-topic, override of a **stylesheet enqueue** is **on topic**. How is the Plugin enqueueing its stylesheet? Please post the relevant code, and we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CSS-related question, more than a Wordpress related one. In your case all the rules that apply for normal CSS overriding are usable to solve your problem:

- **Cascade**: Apply the rules with the same specificity (same number and types of selectors) after the rules written by your plugin. The way to achieve this depends on which *hook* your plugin uses to *enqueue its styles*; you can look at the source code and check for that and then use the priority argument of the hook to achieve proper cascading.
- **Specificity**: Simply be more specific than the rule you want to overwrite. [Read more about specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FSpecificity).
- **Use `!important`**: add `!important` after the rule you want to display and you will win all *specificity/cascade* wars… ever. Hence, this is not really recommended when you have other options.
- **Use inline styles**: This is strongly not recommended, because it's usually a bad practice. I am putting it out there just for the sake of completeness, hence I will not elaborate on that.